# Spring MVC Parameter Handling Discrepancy Between Versions 4.3.7 and 5.3.18: Missing Long Parameter Issue

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Here is my Java controller code snippet:

```java
@RequestMapping("/testRequestParamWithDifferentType")
public String testRequestParamWithDifferentType(@RequestParam(value = "string") String string,
                                                @RequestParam(value = "along") Long along,
                                                @RequestParam(value = "integer") Integer integer) {
    System.out.println("string: " + string + ", along: " + along + ", integer: " + integer);
    return "success";
}
```

In my testing, I accessed the following URL: http://localhost:8080/springMVC/testRequestParamWithDifferentType?string=&along=&integer=

When running this code with Spring MVC version 4.3.7.RELEASE, it functions correctly even though the string, along, and integer parameters are all null. However, upon upgrading to Spring MVC version 5.3.18, the server returns a 400 Bad Request error with the message: "Required Long parameter 'along' is not present."

What could be the underlying reason for this change in behavior?